# Azure Data Factory copy from folder onwards

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a copy activity between two Azure Data Lakes GEN1. I don't need to copy all the folders from the source Data Lake, for example if I have the following directory structure:

```
rootFolder/subfolder/2015
rootFolder/subfolder/2016
rootFolder/subfolder/2017
rootFolder/subfolder/2018
rootFolder/subfolder/2019
rootFolder/subfolder/2020
```

I would just want to copy the data from folders from 2017 onwards.

Is there a way to implement this automatically without specifying the field as a parameter and setting it when the pipeline run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Get MetaData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) Activity,[For Each Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity),[If Condition Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity) may implement your requirement.Please refer to my idea:

Firstly, my test files resides in the ADLS as below:

[image]

`test1.json` in 2016, `test2.json` in 2017, `test3.json` in 2018

In ADF, 1st layer:

[image]

Dataset for Get Metadata Activity:

[image]

[image]

Configuration for For Each Activity:

[image]

Then,2nd layer:

[image]

[image]

Finally,3rd layer:

[image]

Source Dataset in copy activity:

[image]

Test result,only `test1` and `test2` was pulled out.

[image]

So,it does works for me.Any concern,pls let me know.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer, but I have a couple more questions. Would it be possible to have a wildcard folder path in the source dataset? such that the path is something like for example: `rootFolder/subfolder1/*/subfolder3/ 2017`. And would this logic be possible if the final folders were `YYYY=2017`, `YYYY=2018`.. instead of just the year? Therefore the path would be `rootFolder/subfolder1/*/subfolder3/YYYY=2017`. Thank you very much for your help once again.

Comment: @MikelLaburu So,i got your main concern. You folder path named rule is `YYYY=2017`, not `2017`. So you just wanna know how to compare that further,am i right?

Comment: Yes, and sorry if they are somewhat simple questions but I am new to azure and azure data factory.

Comment: @MikelLaburu If i got you correct, the folder name will have "YYYY=2017" instead of "2017". In that case if condition logic instead of using @lessOrEquals(int(item().name),2017), you need to take substring of endpart [YYYY=2017] as follows: @lessOrEquals(int(substring(item().name,5,4)),2017). Hope it hepls :)

Comment: @Hyndavi Thank you for your sharing, your solution is absolutely right.

Comment: @MikelLaburu Hi,you could use `substring` method to refine the expression, @Hyndavi's idea is right. Any further question,just let me know.